# How to `kubectl get all` in k9s?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Instead of navigating a namespace via e.g. `:service`, then `:pod` etc, I would like to see everything that's in the namespace in a single view. As if you would type `kubectl -n argocd get all`.

Can't find the info in the docs. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting community wiki answer based on GitHub topic - [Show multiple resource types without having to switch](https://github.com/derailed/k9s/issues/771). Feel free to expand it.

---

That's true, there is no information about this in the documentation because simply there is no such possibility. There is [open issue with this request on the GitHub page of k9s](https://github.com/derailed/k9s/issues/771#issue-640485968):

> **Is your feature request related to a problem? Please describe.**
> Oftentimes I'm watching/working on multiple resource types at the same time and it's very helpful to not have to switch from one to another. This is something very like  `kubectl get pod,deploy,...`  or  `kubectl get-all`  commands allows
>
> **Describe the solution you'd like**
> Being able to see multiple or all resources in the same screen without having to switch between resource types like:
> `:pod,configmap`  shows all pods & configmaps in the current namespace
> or
> `:all`  shows all resources in the current namespace (get-all like)

Last [pinged November 4 2021](https://github.com/derailed/k9s/issues/771#issuecomment-960530786).

Answer (score -8):

You can try

```
kubectl get all -n argocd -o yaml
```

or

```
kubectl get all -n argocd -o json
```

to list all common resources in a particular namespace

Note: It will not list the CRD or other custom resources like helm

Comment: Thanks, but the question was how to do that in `k9s`.